# NopCommerce SSL loads Images on HTTP, so the browser shows insecure content

Tags: ssl, https, nopcommerce

I tried loading NopCommerce from HTTPS protocol, but Images and Scripts has absolute URL which contains http:// so browser blocks them and shows insecure site instead of green ssl lock.

How should I change absolute url of contents with relatives

Comment: How did you configure SSL? is `force ssl on all pages` is enabled?

Comment: Yes I did enable it

Comment: Try restarting your site. Image URL are being cached. So if you enforce SSL after you visited some parts of your site you have to clear cache or restart your site.